# Using multiple porterduffmodes with bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a problem trying to achieve particular blending situation:

- Create canvas
- Draw raw bitmap
- Draw rect with color and multiply mode
- Draw another rect with color and lighten mode

Following code is working solution with iOS:

```
+ (UIImage *)compositeBackgroundImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
if (image.size.width < 1 || image.size.height < 1)
    return nil;

UIColor *multiplyColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UIColor *lightenColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, multiplyColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextFillRect(c, rect);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, lightenColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeLighten);
CGContextFillRect(c, rect);

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return result;
```

}

And this is corresponding with Java with Android Universal Image Loader with custom `BitmapDisplayer`:

```
.displayer(new BitmapDisplayer() {

    @Override
    public void display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageAware imageAware,
            LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
            int multiplyColor = // color here
            int lightenColor = // color here
            Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            p.setFilterBitmap(true);

            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,
                    Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);

            p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
                    multiplyColor, Mode.MULTIPLY));
            c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

            p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
                    lightenColor, Mode.LIGHTEN));
            c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

            ((ImageView) imageAware.getWrappedView())
                    .setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
```

The result is just a mess far away from iOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of different tries ended up using shader to draw 3 rectangles. The visual look seems to be very close, if someone knows if this does exact same than the iOS code that would be nice.

```
int w = bitmap.getWidth();
int h = bitmap.getHeight();

if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
    int multiplyColor = // get color
    int lightenColor = // get color

    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
            TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    p.setShader(shader);

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

    p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
            multiplyColor, Mode.MULTIPLY));
    c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

    p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
            lightenColor, Mode.LIGHTEN));
    c.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, p);

    ((ImageView) imageAware.getWrappedView())
            .setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```